# How to handle reading in multiple input files?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am creating a dynamic web page and I have a design question.  I have not started hard coding this yet because I wanted to know if I am taking the correct approach.

My web page has a couple of divs that contain passages of a book. When the user hits the next passage button, I want the web page to read in the next passage(external file) and refresh the content of the divs.

I had two dilemmas:

1. How should I handle the external text files?  Each one of these files will contain a pre-reading, post-reading, title, and passage attribute. When I originally tried to code this, I was planning on using JSON, but I had no success. Chrome would not allow to fetch my JSON file.   So there are going to be around 20 chapters and each chapter has 4 attributes.Any suggestions to what type of files they should be saved as that would be very helpful.
2. Once we have decided on which type of files we are going to read in, how would I go along with reading in these files dynamically?  I was thinking it would be the best to load in the data file using JQuery. Then, parse the input for the certain attribute, save the attributes as variables. Finally, I would change the elements in my html by their id's.  Would something like this work? Are there any obvious flaws, or better ways to do this?

Thank you very much for comments!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use JSON, it's easy to work with it on client side.
2. Here is the easiest way to achieve your goal:

Javascript

```
 $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: url,
      success: function(resp) {
          var data = resp; // resp is your JSON object.
      },
      error: function(errorResp) {
         console.error("Failed to get data from server:", errorResp);
      }
 });
```

If you need to read multiple files, just call this function for each of them, or place all files content in same json file on server.

And first check that you can get the content of the files by just hitting the url (link to the file) in browser, if you will not see the content(valid json), you need to check your web server.